# Create a stored procedure based on known columns (wont break on unknown)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have a table with over 100 columns and a database guy who likes to add new ones as he feels;
is there a way to write a stored proc insert that will insert into the known columns (ignoring the extras); like insert set column1 = x

Comment: If you know the columns why dont you just "name" then in the insert SP?

Comment: Ye, my brain unfortunately chose to stop being stupid 2 minutes after posting the question; too late to delete it at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends entirely on the database you are using, if the database allows for certain values to be `NULL` or if the defaults are set up correctly, you can `INSERT` into specific columns.

```
INSERT INTO myCrazyHugeTable (column1Name, column2Name)
    VALUES ('column1Val', 'column2Val');
```

I would be asking some serious questions about:

- Why you have a table with over 100 columns
- Why the structure is so volatile

Comment: Clients table not my own :| and yep they probably dont know what the word normalisation is and are a tad protective (probably hiding the mess)

Comment: Get your consultancy hat on and educate them! :)

Comment: He he; its a double edged sword their real world systems (tills etc) are linked up to this thing. Luckily 131 of the columns in this table are nullable, it just makes me edgy tip toeing through a minefield when the mines have the ability to up root and move :D